# php array to javascript based off of button click

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, forms

Overview - you click on a button(on a javascript page), that will send a request to a php page to pull up a specific array, then that array should be sent back to the javascript page. When that array is passed into the javascript page, I need to pass it into a function for use. Does anyone know of what to do.

What I am currently doing is below -

```
<form action="GetTest.php" method="post">
    Something: <input id = "something" input type="submit" name="q" on/>
</form>
```

When i click on submit, I am redirected to my php page which has the array I need(which is expected), but I don't know what to do from there onwards. Any help on this will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Look into AJAX with JSON, most likely using the jQuery `$.ajax()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, handle the HTML so that you aren't passing it over to the PHP form at all (staying on the page):

Changing:

```
<form action="GetTest.php" method="post">
    Something: <input id = "something" input type="submit" name="q" on/>
</form>
```

To:

```
    Something: <input id = "something" input type="submit" name="q" on/>
```

Then, look into jQuery's AJAX functionality:

```
$("#something").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'GetTest.php',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){
        alert('success');
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('failure');
      }
    });
});
```

You can retrieve the POST data from GetTest.php and transfer it directly through Javascript as a result.

Good luck!

Comment: I think I am missing something, I just wrote this in my code. But, I still get sent to my php page when i click on my button. What I need that button is to pull the php array while still staying on the javascript page, any idea on this at all

Answer (score 2):

You have two methods that can help you:

1. **Using `GET` or `POST` values** - in your case `POST`. Inside `GetTest.php` use `$_POST` variables to handle the data received from your form.

   *Reference:* [$_POST documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)
2. **Using AJAX functionality**. In this case you will be using `XMLHTTPRequest` or `$.ajax` (if you are about to use jQuery).

   *Reference:* [Using jQuery and AJAX - NetTuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/), or [AJAX Tutorial - W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

Comment: +1 for linking to learning resources for this rather than giving code. Would definitely suggest using the jquery implementation to minimise cross browser issues

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, definitely going the jquery route!!